# What do they call "a software developer" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, software

What is the right word for "a software developer" in German? For example:

```
- What do you do?
- I'm a software developer.
```

Comment: [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=software+developer)

Comment: Great dictionary, thank you. There is even a pronunciation there.

Comment: @Green Welcome to our site. Unfortunately, mere translation requests are off-topic here as we're not a translation service but rather concern about more 'serious' issues. This may include translation on a higher level, but simple one-word translation requests basically don't belong to this site. Thus, this question likely will be closed soon. - Considering future questions, please see our [help center](http://german.stackexchange.com/help) to validate if your question is within our scope.

Answer (score 5):

Such a person is called a [Softwareentwickler](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softwareentwickler).

Comment: Danke....... :)